# Why is that Mysql 5.6 runs slower than Mysql 5.5 on the same codebase?

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.5

We've just moved to a new server, both run ubuntu 14.04LTS, the only difference is basically that the old server ran mysql5.5, the new one has mysql5.6. Both servers are cloud machines hosted by digitalocean. Both operate on default my.cnf settings, not much has been tweaked.

An other important difference is, that the new server has double the RAM, and CPU power.

Still - while old server ran with an avg of 0.6 second response time for an api call we monitor server health with, the new one is 1.6-1.8 slower. Yes, they contain heavy joins, but that's not my point - the codebase is exactly the same, and the machine itself is supposed to be stronger. New server also shows peaks of CPU usage few times every hour, which never happened with mysql 5.5.

[image]
Does this make any sense? For me, not so much, but I'm no MySQL guru.

Ran MySQL Tuner, but unsure if there's anything relevant within:

- mysqltuner output for OLD server:
  http://pastebin.com/cqSSssW0
- mysqltuner output for NEW server:
  http://pastebin.com/uk3g1KZa

The only thing that has been tweaked in my.cnf is that it should log slow queries.

Any idea, why this could happen? MySQL5.6 clearly runs faster on benchmarks I saw online. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Tuner output "New Server": `[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 1893`, how's that happening? I'd look at how you moved your databases. Maybe the indices where not moved over.

Comment: Thanks martinczerwi for taking a look. Copied the db with mysqldump, so the indices should be there. You're right that it's a problem, and I have a couple of sketchy joins for now, but since they were also ran on the old machine, I assumed they are not related to the performance drop.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how the tuner works, but just ran it on my dev vm with mysql 5.5, and got No joins without indexes. I first thought that output might be a feature of 5.6, but seems not to be. I don't see any join info in your 5.5 dump unfortunately. **EDIT: Not used logging option `log-queries-not-using-indexes`, that was the reason**

Comment: yep, haven't changed default config settings for 5.5, so logging for queries not using indexes option is off.

Comment: Let's see your queries, together with `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for them.  Also `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Possibly the optimizer is picking the wrong index in some cases.

Comment: `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should, if possible, be bigger than the dataset size, which seems to be 425M.  But don't make it bugger than 70% of _available_ RAM.